# Redis store (or any database?) lock mechanism (NodeJS)

Tags: database, node.js, locking, redis, storage

I have the following problem: I'm using [Redis](http://redis.io/) with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) together via [mranney's driver](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) and my NodeJS webserver is retrieving some data from Redis, doing some operations on it and saving it back to the Redis. But this operation (call it X) may take a while so multiple users can fire it at the same time on the same resources.

So if a user A fires X and user B fires X at the same time I want user A to finish the job and then user B to get the (processed) data and do X. In the meantime user B waits. The order of users is irrelevant - only that one-at-a-time. So how to achieve this in my scenario? How to lock/unlock Redis? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to implement locking in Redis, without knowing more about scenario it sounds like `SETNX` would work. See [Design pattern: Locking with `SETNX`](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) in the Redis documentation. Also, [transactions in Redis](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) might be interesting reading, although I suspect it's not exactly what you're after in this case.

Comment: Great link! I think this is exactly what I need! I already knew about transactions but couldn't find anything on locking. Thank you very much. :)