# How to handle parallel requests from same user in nodejs

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, python-requests

For example:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  // I want to check.
  // If we are already authenticating this user from the given IP.
  // then res.send('Authentication already in progress');
});
```

I'm interested in how to correctly process a request in such moments.
I'm just reading "secure-your-node-js-web-application" of Karl Duuna. And he shows how to stop attackers from running parallel checks about a user’s account. But he mentions that examples have been simplified and are not directly usable in a production environment. So I want to know how to do that in real project. If I don't need to do anything why he wrote that.

Comment: @xaqron - I'm just reading "secure-your-node-js-web-application" of Karl Duuna. And he shows how to stop attackers from running parallel checks about a user’s account. But he mentions that  examples have been simplified and are not directly usable in a production environment. So I want to know how to do that in real project. If I don't need to do anything why he wrote that. Thank you for answer.

Comment: You need to use `session` or other means of storing user `state` for this (session at user side is tracked by cookie and at server side is is stored at a global object). You can do that kind of protection via [IDS/IPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) much easier.

Comment: @xaqron - Can you give me some link to an article that more precisely explain how can I do that via IDS/IPS?

Comment: First decide on the `IPS` type according to your policy/budget/OS. You can use `Host Intrusion Detection Systems (HIDS)` like `Fail2Ban` or `Network Intrusion Detection Systems (NIDS)` or services like `Cloudflare` (preferred). In case of `HIDS` you can think of it as a state-full firewall. The details comes after you have decided about the solution. You need to do [rate limiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting) with your solution. With a good IDS/IPS you can concentrate on `layer 7` attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lock based on the identifying feature of the user. Such a lock can persist in Redis as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497432/redis-store-or-any-database-lock-mechanism-nodejs).

Comment: I thought about it)) But will we have problems with performance? Or not?

Comment: Adding a network call and extra logic will definitely impact the performance. If it is substantial or not depends on the scale you are looking at.